# Как подключить удалённый проект в phpstorm?

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, apache2

у меня есть сайт, который работает по локальной сети. в качестве хоста используется виртуальный хост веб-сервера Apache на Ubuntu 16.04. Файлы проекта находятся в папке /var/www/myproject. Пытаюсь подключиться к удаленному серверу по FTP, не получается подключиться. Что я делаю не так?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на сервере запущен ftp?

Comment: ftp на сервере был установлен, но не запущен. Спасибо, вопрос закрыт